# Change subtitle color Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

How to change the color and font subtitled google charts?
already researched enough in forums, I read all documentation google related to it, but without success.

[image: subtitle]

Is my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
'packages': ['bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['aqui em baixo', 'Ocupada', 'Disponível'],
    ['eq1', 10, 24],
    ['eq2', 16, 22],
    ['eq3', 28, 19]
]);

var options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: 500,
    isStacked: true,
    series: [{
        color: '#5fb560'
    }, {
        color: '#db4437'
    }],
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        maxLines: 1
    },
    bar: {
        groupWidth: '75%'
    },
    chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333333'
    },
};

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Comment: This question would be better asked and answered in [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since no config option to style `chart.subtitle`

must change svg directly, when the `'ready'` event fires

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['aqui em baixo', 'Ocupada', 'Disponível'],
      ['eq1', 10, 24],
      ['eq2', 16, 22],
      ['eq3', 28, 19]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: '100%',
      height: 500,
      isStacked: true,
      series: [{
          color: '#5fb560'
        }, {
          color: '#db4437'
      }],
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        maxLines: 1
      },
      bar: {
        groupWidth: '75%'
      },
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333333'
      }
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('text');
      for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        if (labels[i].innerHTML === options.chart.subtitle) {
          labels[i].style.fill = 'magenta';
          labels[i].style.fontFamily = 'Courier';
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```